# Devolver Json al cliente

Tags: api, rest, go

Les explico un poco mi código:

Tengo un formulario que funcionaba bajo PHP y para aprender lo estoy pasando a GO, resulta que quiero verificar si una persona ya esta registrada, con lo cual pido su DNI y lanzo la accion "ExistenciaPersona". Decodifico el JSON del cliente y mando ese DNI a una función que busca en la DB, luego recibo un numero, un 1 o un 0, dependiendo si existe o no. Sin embargo cuando hago Encode solo recibo un {}, no  un numero. Afirmo de que "respuesta" tiene el contenido {0} o {1}.
De igual manera no me gusta esto de hacer una estructura solo para guardar un dato.

Como puedo solucionar esto para que la respuesta sea la deseada? Se puede enviar un JSON sin tener que armar una estructura? Como responderias cuando solo tenes que enviar un numero?

```
type DNI struct {
    Dni string `json:"dnivalue"`
}
type Response struct {
    respuesta int `json:"respuesta"`
}
func PersonaHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            param := r.URL.Query().Get("accion")
            if param == "ExistenciaPersona" {
                var dni DNI
                if r.Body == nil {
                    http.Error(w, "Please send a request body", 400)
                    return
                }

                err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&dni)
                if err != nil {
                    http.Error(w, err.Error(), 409)
                    return
                } else {
                    respuesta := ExistenciaPersona(dni.Dni)

                    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
                    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(respuesta)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Te comparto, si pudieras compartir más de tu código, o la función `ExistenciaPersona(dni.Dni)` hice el siguiente código, pienso que no estás retornando la estructura como tal y por eso no lo convierte a JSON, te comparto el código lo comprobé y funciona excelente,
una recomendación puedes ir consultando con fmt.Println(err) las salidas de errores e ir descartando el error
pasas el siguiente JSON:

**actualización**, si es necesario tener una estructura para tener una salida JSON.

```
{
    "dnivalue": "123H3"
}
```

y retorna el siguiente JSON:

```
{
    "respuesta": 1
}
```

Código:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", PersonaHandler).Methods("POST")
    http.Handle("/", r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

type DNI struct {
    Dni string `json:"dnivalue"`
}
type Response struct {
    Respuesta int `json:"respuesta"`
}

func PersonaHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    param := r.URL.Query().Get("accion")
    if param == "ExistenciaPersona" {
        var dni DNI
        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&dni)
        if err == io.EOF || err != nil {
            http.Error(w, "Empty Body", 400)
            return
        }
        respuesta := ExistenciaPersona(dni.Dni)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(respuesta)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 409)
            return
        }
    }

}

func ExistenciaPersona(dni string) Response {
    var respuesta Response
    if dni == "123H3" {
        respuesta.Respuesta = 1
        return respuesta
    }
    respuesta.Respuesta = 0
    return respuesta
}
```

Comment: `func ExistenciaPersona(dni string) Response {
 db := GetConnectionDB() //traigo la conexion
 defer db.Close()
 cantPers, err := db.
  Collection("persona").
  Find("dni", dni).
  Count()
 log.Print("Cantidad de personas:", cantPers)
 if err != nil {
  log.Print("Error al confirmar existencia de persona: ", err)
 }
 resultado := Response{int(cantPers)}
 return resultado

}`

Esa es mi función ExistenciaPersona, el problema será el casteo que hago al retornar, es un dato uint64?

Con tu respuesta lo pude solucionar, sin embargo aún no se cual fue el problema jaja, gracias!

Comment: Fue todo un gusto